# Error detecting polynomial of Reed-Solomon code

Tags: coding-theory

Don't know if I made this assignment correct, so I'd be very thankful for checking and maybe giving some hints if anything is wrong:

Let $F = GF(26
)$ be K[x] modulo the primitive polynomial $h(x) = 1 +x
^2 +x
^3 +x
^5 +x
^6$
, and let $\alpha$ be the
class of x. The table below gives the binary representation of the elements of $GF(2^6
)$

[image: table]

Let $\beta = 
\alpha^9$
so that $1;\beta ; ... ; \beta^6$ are all distinct and 
$\beta^7 = 1$. Let $g(x) = (1 + x)(\beta + x)(
\beta^2 + x)(
\beta^3 + x)$.
Then g(x) generates a Reed-Solomon code RS(7;5) over F of length n = 7 and design distance  $\delta= 5$. Note
that this is the general case of Reed-Solomon codes where $\beta$  is not necessarily a primitive element of $GF(2^6
)$.

Compute the error locating polynomial $A(z)$ using the first method as in Section 6.3 (method with forming the extended matrix) if the syndromes
of a received word $w1$ are $s_0 = 
\alpha^{20}; s_1 = \alpha; s2 = 
\alpha^{15}; s_3 = 
\alpha^{58}$. Check that $A(\alpha^
3
) = 0$ and factorize A.
Can this happen if an error of weight at most 2 occurred during transmission?

---

So after calculations I've found that ther error locating polynomial $A(z) = \alpha^{18} + \alpha^{26}x+x^2 = (x+\alpha^3)(x+\alpha^{15})$

I don't understand the question if it can happen when an error of weight at most 2 occured during transmission? It can because the error locating polynomial has 2 roots, therefore it can find locations of at most 2 errors? (+ while calculating the rank of extenden matrix was 2, so there were 2 errors) ?

Also how to interprete "Let $\beta = 
\alpha^9$"? obviously like here the error can't be on place 15 because th code length is only 7? how to transform it to $\beta$?

Comment: Is $\alpha$ a primitive element of $GF(64)$? What is its minimial polynomial? What is the method of Section 6.3? How are the syndromes defined in this particular case? It is unlikely that anyone here would have the same textbook that you study :-)

Comment: I've added the table and the polynomial for creating it :-)  The method is on forming the extended matrix from $\begin{bmatrix} S_{m+1} & S_{m+2} \\ S_{m+2} & S_{m+3} \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} \delta_0 \\ \delta_1 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} S_{m+e+1} \\ S_{m+e+2} \end{bmatrix}$

Answer (score 4):

The point that you are being asked to comprehend here is that just because you find *an* error-locator polynomial (by solving what is sometimes called the *key equation* for Reed-Solomon and more generally of BCH) decoding that factors into linear factors over the field, it is not necessarily *the* error-locator polynomial
of the error pattern that actually occurred.

With a cyclic RS code of length $7$ over GF$(2^6)$, the syndrome values can
be *any* arbitrarily chosen $4$ elements of GF$(2^6)$, but only a few of the
$(2^6)^4$ possible syndromes correspond to correctable error patterns of weight
$2$ or less. In most of the cases, the error-locator polynomial found by
solving the key equation does not factor into linear factors over the field,
and so we can *detect* that more than $2$ errors have occurred even though
we cannot correct them. In some cases including the one that you are
looking at, the error-locator polynomial *does* factor into linear factors,
but the inverses of the roots cannot possibly be the error locations.
Valid error locations are all the $7$-th roots of unity (that is,
powers of $\beta$), and the error locations that you found are not $7$-th
roots.  Thus, *no* error pattern of weight $2$ or less could have caused
this syndrome.

As a practical matter, the roots of the error-locator polynomial
are found by a process called the *Chien search* which consists
of simply evaluating the error-locator polynomial at the powers
of $\beta$. (The reason that such an unsophisticated method is used is that
it simplifies the implementation of a BCH decoder in hardware, and to
some extent in software too). The results of the Chien search will be
that the error-locator polynomial does not have as many roots as
its degree among the $7$-th roots of unity, and so an uncorrectable
error pattern has occurred.